# Can I get the default template name from my route when I use renderTemplate?

Tags: ember.js

I'll use renderTemplate to place my modal at the application level. I'd prefer it if I could get the default tempalte name instead of `plush-toys.item.info`.

```
renderTemplate() {
  this.render('plush-toys.item.info', {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'modal'
  });
}
```

How can I get it from the route?

Comment: `templateName` property - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_templateName

Comment: if that's what you are looking for then i will add it as answer.